# How to get min/max and avg lengths of text field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with the following mapping:

```
        "properties": {
            "content": {
                "type":  "text",                
            },
            "ar_name": {
                "type": "text"
            }

        }
```

I want to get statistics (min length, max length and average length) to the `content`
field.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`string_stats` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-aggregations-metrics-string-stats-aggregation.html) provides that support but only for `keyword` fields. Since your content field is of type `text`, I assume it contains free-text that is not really suitable as `keyword`.

If that's the case, I would suggest that you stored the length of the `content` field in another integer field (e.g. `content_length`) that you can then use in a [`stats` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html) that would return you the metrics you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep field as text or you don't want to change the mapping, you can achieve this by a script in aggregation. Here is an example query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "min": {
      "min": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            return doc['content'].value.length();
          """
        }
      }
    },
    "max": {
      "max": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            return doc['content'].value.length();
          """
        }
      }
    },
    "avg": {
      "avg": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
            return doc['content'].value.length();
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that using scripts in aggregations is ok for proving the concept, but the value should then be pre-computed and stored in a field of the document, otherwise depending on the volume of data this aggregation query is run on, the performance of the cluster might suffer considerably.

Comment: Agree, it is just another way of doing it without changing the mapping. It can cause performance problems and first choice should always be solving this at indexing time.

Comment: Yes, agreed, a quick PoC with scripts on a small data set is always ok, but then you should be doing this at indexing time for better performance.

Comment: I'm trying to run the code you suggest and I'm getting elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')

Comment: Do you have details of the exception? It would make easier if you can share. And are the any null values in content fields? If there are, you should add a null check in the script.